# How to getResource from Bootstrap Class Loader?

Tags: java, classloader

In a Java application, the Bootstrap Class Loader (which is used to load classes from JRE such as rt.jar) is null. That is, `java.util.ArrayList.class.getClassLoader() == null`.

This is annoying because when writing a library that uses reflection, one must use the appropriate class loader, which sometimes is null. So in case the ClassLoader is null, a library should call `Class.forName(String, false, classLoader)` instead of `classLoader.loadClass(String)`. By the way, the static method `Proxy.newProxyInstance(classLoader, interfaces, invocationHandler)` works fine when the classLoader is null.

But is there any equivalent of `ClassLoader.getResource(String)` or `ClassLoader.getResources(String)` that works even when the classLoader is null? The closest I can think of is `new ClassLoader(classLoader).getResource(String)`, but that uses extra SecurityManager permissions than necessary.

Comment: This is how it works. The bootstrap is native code and does not exist as a `ClassLoader` instance.  See http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html

Comment: All bootstrap-resources are loaded from the class-path which is set in system property "sun.boot.class.path" (see also [sun.misc.Launcher](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Launcher.java)). But I could only find a "load resource from classpath" implementation [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/ResponsibleforloadingclassfilesfromtheCLASSPATHInspiredbysuntoolsClassPath.htm) which is not even close to an equivalent of `ClassLoader.getResource(String)`.